# Pass PHP Variable to AJAX Variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, variables

After a completed calculation form where the total is loaded in via PHP we have 4 pieces of data (variables left over with PHP)

$totalprice;
$totalduration;
$totaldives;
$totalhire;

At the moment the PHP ends with echo for each of these. The ajax then collects them like this.

```
success: function() {
                 $('#results').html();
```

The problem is that echos all results.

I would like to send the `$totalprice to $('#resultsprice').html();` the `$totalduration to $('#resultsduration').html();` etc etc...

Any ideas how to do that?

Marvellous

Comment: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: try answering some of your own questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could return a JSON string from PHP:

```
echo json_encode( array('totalprice'=>$totalprice, 'totalduration'=>$totalduration, 'totaldives'=>$totaldives, 'totalhire'=>$totalhire));
```

Then, change your jquery ajax call to set the response to json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#resultsprice').html(data.totalprice);
        $('#resultsduration').html(data.totalduration);
    });
```

Comment: Success function is missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

Use the php function [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). First in php create an array with the 4 variables. Json encode the array and echo the result. Then in jQuery use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the json code to javascript variables. Here's an example:

PHP:

```
$data = array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2', 'var3' => 'value3', 'var4' => 'value14');
echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery:

```
success: function(data) {
     data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**JSON**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) as data format.

In PHP, you can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create a JSON string. [`compact`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) is an easy way to create an associative array from variables:

```
echo json_encode(compact('totalprice', 'totalduration', 'totaldives', 'totalhire'));
// compact produces array('totalprice' => <value-of-totalprice>, ...)
// json_encode produces '{"totalprice": <value>, ...}'
```

In jQuery, set the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option to `json` and the argument passed to the `success` callback will be a JavaScript object:

```
$.ajax({
    // ... all other options ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // use .html() only for HTML data
        $('#resultsprice').text(data.totalprice);
        $('#resultsduration').text(data.totalduration);
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What is actually returned from the AJAX call?  If it's a JSON object containing the various values, you can set each one to various HTML elements.  Something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#resultsprice').html(data.TotalPrice);
    $('#resultsduration').html(data.TotalDuration);
    // etc.
}
```